# what is difference between normal android device and tango device in terms of sensors?

Tags: android, project, google-project-tango

I wanted to ask the features that tango devices have and normal android device 
 (SAMSUNG GT-19505) don't have.

I am confused with the camera that tango have and normal android device like (SAMSUNG GT-19505) have.If i use SAMSUNG GT-19505 with tango API which capabilities of library will i be able to leverage.

Comment: After searching a lot i think difference between them is only in hardware i.e tango device has fish eye camera ,powerfull infared receiver and for rendering the surrounding world in 3D and i think there will be no api for normal android mobile because it will be useless without the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Project Tango has two special cameras and two emitters on the back face:

1. A fish-eye RGB camera for wide-angle video.
2. A Class-1 IR-laser emitter for highlighting surface points.
3. An IR camera for detecting said points (and thereby determining spatial position.)
4. A flash for low-light conditions. (Might perhaps also be useful for assisting mapping efforts in low-light situations.)

Like most modern phones, the Samsung GT-19505 has an RGB camera, and a flash, but lacks the emitter/receiver pair for 3D depth-sensing and area-mapping, rendering the Project Tango SDKs incompatible.